# New API keys in Mandrill by default have full access to your account - can you customize?

Tags: email, mailchimp, mandrill

In Mandrill, if you create a new API key and do not limit its API calls, whoever you give that key to can use it to log into the web interface with full access - billing information, account information, the works.

After playing around, it looks like you can disable the web interface login functionality by ticking "Only Allow This Key To Use Certain API Calls" and then selecting at least one API call. Doesn't matter which one.

So I can give full access to the account, or completely disable their ability to log in. Is there any way to customize this further? I would like to be able to limit users to the outbound/inbound UI, or at least prevent them from having the ability to charge many thousands of dollars to the attached credit card. For clarification, my use case is to distribute API keys to contractors or vendors so that all email gets sent through a single account.

I have found very little official Mandrill documentation on this. The only thing that seemed relevant is that if you have a Mailchimp account, you can instead send users there and use the "View Mandrill Reports" functionality. I don't have Mailchimp (nor do I need it), so this seems like an unnecessary hacky workaround.

Comment: This is a very good point and should be more clearly documented in the Mandrill UI. It poses a potential security risk in my opinion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different levels of access, other than limiting API calls for API keys isn't currently possible as described in the Mandrill KB [here](http://help.mandrill.com/entries/28789183-Can-I-have-multiple-users-or-different-logins-for-a-Mandrill-account-). If someone has access to the web interface, they have access to the account as a whole. This may, of course, change in the future, and would be documented on the blog and in the KB.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could also restrict access to the web interface by setting up two-factor authentication?